# Как сделать так, что бы тень стояла на месте

Tags: html, css

```css
div{
text-align:center;
line-height:5;
color:#fff;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:gray;
border-radius:50%;
box-shadow: 5px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);


}

div:hover{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:gray;
border-radius:50%;
box-shadow: 5px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);

transform: rotate(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div>Привет</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласен с пред идущим ответом, но можно и так...

```css
#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5;
  color: #fff;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(0);
  transition: all .5s;
}

#wrapper:hover #content {
  transition: all .5s;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">Привет</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

при ротации также манять и положение тени

```css
div{
text-align:center;
line-height:5;
color:#fff;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:gray;
border-radius:50%;
box-shadow: 5px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
transition: .3s linear;
transform: rotate(0deg);
}

div:hover{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:gray;
border-radius:50%;
box-shadow: 2px -4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);
transition: .3s linear;
transform: rotate(60deg);
}
```

```html
<div>Привет</div>
```

или пишите анимацию для тени отдельно с координатами. так как сам блок менят свое положение так и тень будет менять свое.

Comment: Но он дергается при этом

Comment: добавил transition: .3s linear; чтоб не дергалась а плавно переходила